# Entity collection best practice (separation of concerns, dependency injection, ...)

Tags: php, design-patterns, collections

I build a collection to ensure only valid entities in an array so I don't have to validate after every function / method call as I could rely on the collection to have only valid entities stored.

```
class WorldCollection implements Collection, ArrayAccess {

    private $container = array();
    private $oValidator;

    public function __construct (Validator $oWorldValidator) {
        $this->oValidator = $oWorldValidator;
    }

    public function offsetExists ($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }


    public function offsetGet ($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

    /**
     * READ ME
     */    
    public function offsetSet ($offset, $value) {
        $this->oValidator->validate($value)
        if (is_null ($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetUnset ($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
}
```

As I want to separate concerns and follow dependency injection I inject the `Validator` in the constructor of the collection and validate in the `ofsetSet` method to ensure only valid values will be stored.

```
class WorldValidator implements Validator {

    public function validate($aWorld) {
        if (!is_array($aWorld)) {
            throw new WorldValidationException('invalid type', WorldValidationException::ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

(The validator is simplified for example purpose.)

1. Did I seperate it right? Or should I handle this
   kind of validation differently?
2. Should I catch the validation exception to not disturb the program
   flow? If so should I store the exception and offer a `getErrors`
   method?
3. Should I rename the collection `ValidWorldCollection` and extend
   from `WorldCollection`?
4. Should the `InvalidWorldException` extend `RuntimeException` or
   `LogicException`? Same for `WorldValidationException` in the
   validator
5. Should I create a World Class and exclude the `Validation` from the
   `Collection` using `instanceof` ?
6. Should I have used a more appropriate Spl DataStructure?
   (SplObjectStorage?)  Or is it all a waste of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Design

Dependency injection is very useful when you have multiple implementations of a given dependency. If you don't plan implementing another `Validator`, then it's probably premature abstraction. I'll assume here that you have other `Validator` implementations.

Let me answer your questions:

1. The separation itself is good.
2. An exception is meant to be catched "whenever possible", and it is not possible in `WorldCollection`, since you don't know how to handle it. You need to wonder what you want your application to do when the data does not validate.

If you want `WorldCollection::offsetSet` to not do anything when the validation fails, then `WorldValidator::validate` should simply return true or false, and no exception should be thrown.

If the exception is to be catched later on in the code, then don't do anything in `WorldCollection::offsetSet`, since another code will take care of the issue.

You can easily mix those two approaches in order to catch some of the exception at some point, and other ones later on (which means `WorldValidator::validate` should always throw an exception, and return nothing).

3. Only if you plan on having other `WorldCollection`s. I don't think so.
4. `LogicException` should only be launched if there is a flow in your program, ie. an exception that would never be thrown in a perfect program. `RuntimeException` is a base class used for errors such as OutOfBounds or Overflow. I'd use [InvalidArgumentException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php).
5. I didn't understand the question. Note that `instanceof` is never good design, and exists to work around design errors.
6. ArrayAccess is a reasonable choice, it lets you do foreach on your data easily, whereas with `Iterator` you would have to implement a ton of methods. `SplObjectStorage` could be used, but only if you don't need the keys `ArrayAccess` provides.

### Implementation

1. Do you want only one exception with different types, such as `ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE`?
2. Why don't you use multiple exceptions?
3. If you want to stick with one exception, don't pass "invalid type" in the constructor, since it is always going to be the same message. Prefer to override `Exception::__toString()` to return "invalid type" when the type is `ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE`.
4. Use offsetExists in offsetGet instead of repeating yourself?
5. Consider using [`NULL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) instead of null, and `TRUE` instead of true, even if they are case-insensitive.
6. `$this->oValidator->validate($value)` forgot a semicolon?
7. Don't use return if you're not going to check the return value.

Comment: **Implementation**
4. i am with you, most of the class is just copy and paste from http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php as is offsetExists 

3. thanks for the advice but i will not discuss coding convention in this topic

4. true

5. well there is always a return , if not a custom one then the return null 

**Design**
5. the point was to limit the the collection by type "world" and to exclude validation from the collection (as it only accepts instance of "World") and let the "World" class handle this kind of stuff 

thx for everything!